# Delete duplicate entries in SQL database table from Python

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I'm trying to delete duplicate entries in a SQL database table from Python with

```
engine = create_engine(database_connection_string)
with engine.connect() as connection:

    column_names_sql_string = ", ".join(column_names)
    delete_query = text(f"DELETE FROM {table_name} WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM {table_name} GROUP BY {column_names_sql_string})")
    delete_result = connection.execute(delete_query)
```

but I get the error `Invalid column name 'id'.`. I don't know how to call the column with the integer indices.

How can I fix this?